# i3: how to have all windows spawned from a window to go into a different split-style than the parent that spawns it

Tags: i3

Here’s a ex layout:

```
  +———————-+ +————————-+
  | (VERT) | | (TABBED)|
  |        | |         |
  | parent | | target  |
  |________| | window  |
  |parent’s| | stack   |
  |neighbor| |         |
  |(same   | |         |
  | stack) | |         |
  |________| |_________|
```

•  My main process is called “parent” — it spawns child windows (think:  ranger is parent, child is pdfs I open;  ex2:  emacs is parent, child is pop-up windows in x11 for preview of images generated)

•  My question:  **I want `parent` to generate its child windows into the `target-window-stack` to its right.**

1. By default, however, i3 generates new windows into the same `window-stack` as the parent. This works 95% of the time and is good. But 5% of the time I have a use-case as above.